# Qt - Bytearray with empty entries?

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I'm working on a simple function which is able to return a int in Qt using information sent to a comport.

I'm using the QSerialPort class which returns a [QBytearray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#toInt).

The problem is i seem (on occasion) to get empty entries in the array that QSerialPort.readAll returns. This makes me unable to convert the bytearray to an int.

The basic functionality is: Ask for Arduino to send either temperature or humidity.

Qt code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString comPort = "COM6";
    QSerialPortInfo ArduinoInfo(comPort);

    cout << "Manufacturer: " << ArduinoInfo.manufacturer().toStdString() << endl;
    cout << "Product Identifier: " << ArduinoInfo.productIdentifier() << endl;
    cout << "Vendor Identifier: " << ArduinoInfo.vendorIdentifier() << endl;

    QSerialPort Arduino(ArduinoInfo);

    Arduino.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    Arduino.open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);

    Sleep(1000);

    if(Arduino.isDataTerminalReady())
        cout << "Great Sucess" << endl;

    char sending = 'H';


    cout << sending << endl;

    Arduino.write(&sending, 1);

    //int maxSize = Arduino.bytesAvailable();

    while(!Arduino.waitForReadyRead()){}
    Sleep(100);

    QByteArray rawDataArry = Arduino.readAll();
    cout << "Shit has been read." << endl;


    // Form here on its just write functions, used for debug

    cout << "rawData:" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < rawDataArry.size(); i++)
        cout << "[" << i << "] "<< rawDataArry[i] << endl;

    cout << "All data:" << endl;
    for(char s:rawDataArry){
        cout << s;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Converted data:" << endl;
    bool ok;
    int returnVar = rawDataArry.toInt(&ok, 10);
    cout << returnVar << endl;
    cout << "Convertion Status:" << ok;

    Arduino.close();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The Arduino code is super simple.

```
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;

#define PIN_7 7

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  String impString;

  while(Serial.available() != 1);
  impString = Serial.readString();

  DHT.read11(PIN_7);

  if(impString == "T")
  {
    int temp = DHT.temperature;
    Serial.println(temp);
  }
  else if(impString == "H")
  {
    int humid = DHT.humidity;
    Serial.println(humid); 
  }

  emptyReceiveBuf();
  delay(100);
}

void emptyReceiveBuf()
{
  int x;
  delay(200);  // vent lige 200 ms paa at alt er kommet over

  while (0 < Serial.available())
  {
    x = Serial.read();
  }
}
```

Terminal  monitor displays:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: You might find `QByteArray::toHex()` method helpful, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a member of QByteArray to clean up the widespaces in the array!

It looks something like this!

```
bool ok;
int returnVal;

do
{
  Arduino.write(&imputChar, 1); // Arduino input Char

  Arduino.waitForReadyRead();

  QByteArray rawDataArry(Arduino.readAll()); // Empties buffer into rawDataArry 
  QByteArray dataArray(rawDataArry.simplified()); // Removes all widespaces!

  returnVal = dataArray.toInt(&ok, 10); // Retuns ByteConvertion - &OK is true if convertion has completed - Widespaces will ruin the conversion

  qDebug() << "Converted data:";
  qDebug() << returnVal;
  qDebug() << "Convertion Status:" << ok;
  }while(ok != 1);

  return(returnVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `rawDataArry.size()` is returning 4, so that means there ARE 4 bytes in the array. However, when you call `rawDataArry[i]` it returns a char. Not every char value can be represented as an ascii character. Which is why the last 2 bytes appear empty.

Instead you should try to convert each char to a value that shows the decimal/hex representation of the byte instead of the ascii representation.

Alternatively, you could convert those 4 bytes right to an int and be done with it:

```
//Big Endian
quint32 myValue(0);
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    myValue = myValue + (quint8(rawDataArry.at(i)) << (3-i)*8);
//myValue should now have your integer value
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! - I became aware of the fact that QByteArray had a member which is able to remove all empty entries and widespaces. It ended up working fine!